# Join multiple videos with fade in/out without reencoding the whole video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to join multiple videos with a cross-fade inbetween.

I know that I can simply reencode every video with the desired fades and then just join them.
That would look like:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -y -vf fade=in:st=0:d=5,fade=out:st=273.72:d=5 -af afade=in:st=0:d=5,afade=out:st=273.72:d=5 out.mp4
```

But that of course needs to reencode the entire video.

My idea was to create a fade-in and fade-out clip of each video which would be 5 seconds and then remove 5 seconds at the start and the end of the full video, repeat that for each video and then merge them in order (video1, video1-fadeout, video2-fadein, video2, video2-fadeout, ...). This way, I would only need to reencode the fade-in/out and could re-use most of the original video as is.

This basically works but the cuts between the video and the fadein or fadeout are not clean. Probably due to keyframes or because of the concatenation of different encoded videos afterwards.

Has anyone done something similar or could help on how to achieve this?

**Edit 1:**

Ok I kind of got it working. One of the keys is to only crop from keyframe to keyframe. I do this by using ffprobe to get the nearest keyframe, so for example `fprobe -read_intervals 10.8%+10 -select_streams v -skip_frame nokey -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=print_section=0 <video>` returns a list of the keyframes from 10.8 seconds to 20.8 seconds, I can then just use the first result as my keyframe.

Now the more interesting thing follows now:

If I now use splitting with `-ss` *before* `-i` it still messes up *unless* I substract a value (PTS of first frame? the value that avidemux shows on the first frame, 0.080 seconds in my case) from all keyframe times. Then it works and is still fast. But is that value correct? And how can I get it without avidemux?

The other approach is to use `-ss` *after* `-i`. Then it works without adding or substracting anything to the timestamps but is of course slower (according to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking).

So I am now stuck with a slow variant which seems correct or a fast variant with a magic number I cannot explain (yet).